# I do not understand why my method for adding nodes into binary tree does not work?

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I am trying to learn Python better, and I know one can easily find the solution for adding items into BTS, but I do not understand **why** my implementation of add method does not work? Can someone please help?

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, left = None, right = None):
      self.data = data
      self.left = left
      self.right = right
class Tree:

   def __init__(self):
       self.root = None

   def add(self, data):
      self.root = self._add(data,self.root)
      # if I change this line with just "self._add(data,self.root)" it would not iterate tree at all..

   def _add(self,data,root):

      if root is None:
         root = Node(data)
         return root
      elif data <= root.data:
         root.left = self._add(data, root.left)
      else:
         root.right = self._add(data,root.right)

   def in_order(self):
      if self.root is not None:
            self._in_order(self.root)

   def _in_order(self, root):
      if root is not None:
            self._in_order(root.left)
            print(str(root.data) + ' ')
            self._in_order(root.right)
```

I am printing in classical in-order fashion. My question is after inserting a few numbers, why do I still get the result for a root node to be None ?
This kind of implementation worked for me before in C or in Java, but in Python it does not work.
EDIT: I added my in-order method.

I have also tried this but it also does not work:

```
def add(self,data):
      if self.root == None:
         self.root = Node(data)
      elif data <= self.root.data:
         self.root.left = self.add(self.root.left,data)
      else:
         self.root.right = self.add(self.root.right,data)
```

I get a TypeError: add() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: In the `_add` function you want to assign to `self.root` rather than just `root`.

At the moment you are just modifying the argument to the function, not the instance variable. Maybe also change the name of the argument from `root` to something else. Having an argument with the exact same name as an instance field is confusing.

Comment: I don't see a `__str__` function. How are you printing everything out and determining `root` is None?

Comment: _add doesn't (always) return a value, but you are using it as if it does

Comment: `_add` isn't returning the root in every case, so `self.root` is being set to `None` in many cases in `add`.

Comment: You should probably move `return root` to the end of the method.  Exiting a function without a return value produces None as the output.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is after inserting a few numbers, why do I still get the result for a root node to be None ?

With this following line, you're setting `self.root` to be the return value of the method `_add`. Since this method has no return statement, it returns `None` by default.

```
self.root = self._add(data,self.root)
```

> I get a TypeError: add() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

In this case, you're calling `self.add(self.root.left,data)` with three parameters: the implicit `self` reference, `self.root.left` and `data`.

However, the method declaration receives only the parameters `self` and `data`.